# Can't add a shell build step with docker on containerized Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

Host is a debian 8.4 server

Jenkins is containerized and launched with

```
docker run -d --name myjenkins -p 9090:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --restart="always" myjenk
```

from the dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y sudo \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

I have a simple build configured as such:
[build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euRYL.png)

the build Dockerfile being

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER Poirey Nicolas <fake@mail.com>

WORKDIR /16AGR/frontend

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "install" ]
```

I get this error:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/npoirey/16AGR.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/npoirey/16AGR.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/npoirey/16AGR.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06
 > git rev-list bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 # timeout=10
Build Docker image from ./frontend//Dockerfile ...
$ docker build --file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2/frontend/Dockerfile /var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2/frontend
Sending build context to Docker daemon 93.18 kB

Step 1 : FROM node:latest
 ---> d1699fb7d2bf
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Poirey Nicolas <fake@mail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 787f355d0144
Step 3 : WORKDIR /16AGR/frontend
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 083aa873e30a
Step 4 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 53eb0ed184a9
Step 5 : CMD npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2917019ab455
Successfully built 2917019ab455
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/true alpine:3.2
$ docker run --tty --rm --entrypoint /sbin/ip alpine:3.2 route
$ docker run --tty --detach --privileged --workdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2 --volume /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:rw --volume /tmp:/tmp:rw --net bridge --add-host dockerhost:172.17.0.1 --env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#4 --env BUILD_ID=4 --env BUILD_NUMBER=4 --env BUILD_TAG=jenkins-frontend-unit-test-2-4 --env CLASSPATH= --env EXECUTOR_NUMBER=1 --env GIT_BRANCH=origin/master --env GIT_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 --env GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 --env GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 --env GIT_URL=https://github.com/npoirey/16AGR.git --env HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home --env HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=23e53af9086f2739 --env JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=23e53af9086f2739 --env JOB_BASE_NAME=frontend-unit-test-2 --env JOB_NAME=frontend-unit-test-2 --env NODE_LABELS=master --env NODE_NAME=master --env WORKSPACE=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2 2917019ab455 /bin/cat
Docker container fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109 started to host the build
$ docker exec --tty fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109 env
[frontend-unit-test-2] $ docker exec --tty --user 0:0 fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109 env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#4 BUILD_ID=4 BUILD_NUMBER=4 BUILD_TAG=jenkins-frontend-unit-test-2-4 CLASSPATH= EXECUTOR_NUMBER=1 GIT_BRANCH=origin/master GIT_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=bb7291657427c118a5df4d97d070a7abb90f8f06 GIT_URL=https://github.com/npoirey/16AGR.git HOME=/root HOSTNAME=fe9a8942f1d9 HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=23e53af9086f2739 JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=23e53af9086f2739 JOB_BASE_NAME=frontend-unit-test-2 JOB_NAME=frontend-unit-test-2 NODE_LABELS=master NODE_NAME=master NODE_VERSION=7.3.0 NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin TERM=xterm WORKSPACE=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/frontend-unit-test-2 /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson178227185989971526.sh
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /tmp/hudson178227185989971526.sh
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Stopping Docker container after build completion
$ docker kill fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109
fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109
$ docker rm --force fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109
fe9a8942f1d9665a799c90ee796cdc47dcb73c1bfaf4bd09c515bc1ddb509109
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I remove the build step no error is thown

I don't really understand what i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: `Npm install` is a command that completes, so it is normal that your container exits

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, I just tried the same build but using node image instead of a dockerfile and ran in the same problem
Can't open /tmp/hudson178227185989971526.sh
 
I also tried exactly the same build but on a jenkins installed directly on the server and not running in docker successfully. I am obviously missing something about running jenkins in docker but I don't see what

Comment: I do not see what you expect your container to do, a nginx container launches nginx, a Wordpress container launches Wordpress, but `npm install` ok and then? If you want to stick to that idea, you can do `npm install ; sleep infinity` you ld have a look at CMD and ENTRYPOINT directives for a Dockerfile, see the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd  and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint

Comment: this dockerfile is the one i'm using as my dev env, I wanted to make my dev/ci env the same. In jenkins I intended to add a build step to run "npm test". This works on a jenkins that isn't itself running in a container. Here it seems that the container is run with cat which should not return, and then fail when running exec because it can't find the temporary file containing the build step set in jenkins. I will have a look at your links tomorow, thanks